# How to hide specific questions on the "Graphical Summary of Responses" Sharepoint Survey Page?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Some of the survey questions are unique text entries and some checkboxes. I want to hide just the questions that are unique text entries, because the results page displays them as a gigantic list.

I tried running the following code in a CEWP, but it was not working?

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   $('h3:contains("1. What was the USO or Circuit ID?")').hide().next("table").hide();})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After much googling I figured it out.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" unselectable="on">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" unselectable="on">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('h3:contains("What was the USO or Circuit ID?")').hide().next("table").hide();
})
</script>
```

This hid my question. Just go to the graphical summary page. Insert a CEWP, then click insert embedded code, and use the above.

If you want to adapt this code just change the "What was the USO or Circuit ID?" to the question, you're trying to hide